# Displaying only specific galleries using shortcode on a custom page

Tags: gallery

I have finally got the gallery working on my page, and following some previous advice on this site I researched the shortcode for the gallery on the codex. Now if I understood correctly if I set ID to say id="astrophoto" it should only read from that post, but when I call the page up it grabs images that are not included in the post gallery.

Also comes a question of styling. I am using Foundation 4 as my framework and I was planning on using the modal included for displaying the full size images when clicked, but it has taken and I am hoping to save time on this part and get some help from here.

gallery location: http://lab.nmjgraphics.com/astrophotography/

here is the shortcode I am using right now:

```
<?php
//Calling arguments for gallery. This is the place to change the information for which gallery is to be displayed
$gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="astrophoto" columns="3" order="ASC" orderby="ID" gallery size="medium"]';
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<h1 class="contact-title">Astrophotography Gallery</h1>

<div class="row">
<?php print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode ); ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: First of all... You don't have to do it with `<?php print apply_filters( 'the_content', $gallery_shortcode ); ?>`. It would be much nicer, if you'd use `<?php echo do_shortcode($gallery_shortcode); ?>`

Comment: I was just following off the codex examples, making the change now.

Comment: Still not having any luck with this

Comment: Me comment wasn't solution to question (it wasn't answer). I've just noticed not so nice part of your code. What is your problem exactly - your code looks OK to me, so it should work, I guess.

Comment: I am wondering if I should do id="x" where x is equal to the post id, instead of the name?

Comment: Yes, you should (as it's explained in Codex) - see my answer.

Comment: okay getting closer. I have the photoshop gallery only displaying, but the astrophotography is now gone.

photoshop post id is 138 and astrophotography is 136 (which are both in the code).

Comment: Show your current code, pls

Comment: `<?php`
    `//Calling arguments for gallery. This is the place to change the information for which gallery is to be displayed`
    `$gallery_shortcode = '[gallery id="136" columns="3" order="ASC" orderby="ID" gallery itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" gallery size="medium"]';`
    `?>`

    `<?php get_header(); ?>`

    `<h1 class="contact-title">Astrophotography Gallery</h1>`

    `<div class="row">`
    `<?php echo do_shortcode($gallery_shortcode); ?>`
    `</div>`

    `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: OK, and what's the problem now?

Comment: so the id is set to the page, but when you go to [link]http://lab.nmjgraphics.com/astrophotography/ it doesn't display, but the photoshop gallery is working fine.

Comment: I will deal with this tomorrow. I am betting it is something silly and overlooked. Thanks for the help Krzysiek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [gallery shortcode documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) (Codex)

> id
>
> specify the post ID. The gallery will display images which are attached to that post. The default behavior, if no ID is specified, is to display images attached to the current post. For example, to display images attached to post 123: [gallery id="123"]

So yes, you should put post_id in there, not post_name.